# Использование онтогенеза для создания искусственного интелекта (ИИ)

Tags: искусственный-интеллект

*Думаю зашедшим с главной немного не понятно, этот вопросопост примыкает [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/269311/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)*

Самый простой способ создать ИИ - создать самообучаемую программу и скормить ей реальный мир. Такое происходит при рождении ребёнка, причём не только человека: начинает видеть мир, слышать речь и таким образом узнаёт новое. А алгоритм самообучения уже вшит в голове.

Онтогенез может помочь ускорить развитие и обучение ИИ. Создаётся несколько роботов c одинаковым алгоритмом. Одного пускают в википедию, другого по чатам интернета, третьего кататься с камерой по улицам. Каждый получает свои знания из своих источников (вот и онтогенез - у каждого своё развитие), а потом они они сливают все свои знания вместе и получается умненький ИИ :)

З.ы. придумка моя, но уверен, что кто-нибудь до меня уже до того додумался

Comment: а где вопрос-то?

Comment: @DreamChild это не вопрос, просто в комментарии это не влезает :)

Comment: @danpetruk, так надо было это оформить как ответ к тому вопросу.



А вообще Ваш пост аналогичен "у меня идея! Чтобы ускорить какой-то алгоритм, можно разделить данные на части и каждую часть обсчитать на отдельном процессоре, а потом соединить". Как бы да, идея хорошая, но осталось ещё сделать ИИ и научиться объединять результаты

Comment: IMHO сейчас эта идея развивается под модным именем [MapReduce](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

--

@Михаил М, а каким образом можно сделать ответ в разделе **Исследования**?

IMHO там можно только комментировать.

--

А вообще-то, мне кажется, что к *онтогенезу* все это отношения не имеет (возможно @mikillskegg расскажет подробнее).

Comment: @avp, хм, действительно, похоже, нельзя. Прошу прощения, воспринимал исследования как вопросы-директории

Comment: Нужно написать программу которая случайным образом постоянно себя модифицирует и в результате миллиардов лет эволюции она себя модифицирует до искуственного интеллекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что, для саморазвития нужна **цель,** нужна **воля**, необходимо чтобы ИИ **сам** чегото желал, сам ставил себе  цели, как Вы собиратесь это моделировать или запрограммировать? Это основная проблема.

Comment: Этож робот. Конечно его можно вообще запрограммировать, чтоб он ничего не делал, но программирующий задаст ему в алгоритме максимальное любопытство. Как это написать? Вкратце: **робот лазает по интернету, смотрит слова и запоминает, какое с каким словом используется. Анализирует, находит закономерности, что всё, что прозывали "фрукт" - с ними употребляется слово есть.** Однако это много много строк кода и нужен очень очень мощный комп (а лучше сеть). Такие наработки есть у IBM (Waston), больше пожалуй не у кого - слишком много надобно ресурсов

Comment: ну нашел он законемерность, а дальше что? какова цель то конечная?

Comment: ![alt text][1]

[1]: http://i.imgur.com/IzwnXth.jpg